# Analyze_Compensation in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can anyone please tell me for what purpose analyze_compensation is used in oracle?
I got this term in a code in bulk collect. PFB the link:

http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/o28plsql-095155.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to print all the rows and columns of table i.e(Select * from ***table_name***;
) in PL/SQL

THEN in that case :-

dbms_output.put_line() wont be able to print the table data when there is more than one row... Hence we use analyze_compensation() .
It is a procedure , which you need to declare in **DECLARE** BLOCK of PL/SQL

analyze_compensation is used to print the whole table data i.e Select * from ***table_name***;